# Meaning of "root project"

Tags: meaning, terminology, metaphors, attributive-nouns

When I read [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26243909/6366398), the following phrase was quoted from [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Controlling-Android-properties-of-all-your-modules-from-the-main-project):

> in the ***root project*** 's build.gradle:

I do not know meaning of that, and I could not find the meaning.
What does **root project** mean?

Comment: You might thought my question is off-topic, but this cannot be migrated to Stack Overflow, because I got this message. "We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: ...or should this question migrated to other sites?

Comment: Coming to another site to ask questions because you are question banned on Stack Overflow is not an acceptable practice. You need to improve your existing questions over there so that they meet the site's guidelines, which will lift the question ban.

Comment: And I think this is on-topic. So I asked here. (This is also on-topic in Stack Overflow..?)

Comment: I'll rewrite it. "You might thought my question is off-topic, but even if so, this cannot be migrated to Stack Overflow, because I got the message, and I think this is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the documentation is discussing a hierarchy of projects.  In other words, one project can contain other project(s).  There might even be multiple levels of projects within projects within projects.  In computer programming, this kind of structure is called a "tree".  A "directory tree" is a similar structure.

A real-life tree has a trunk, which has branches, which have branches, which have twigs, which have leaves.  At the bottom of the trunk are the roots of the tree.

By analogy, the directory that contains all of the other directories in a directory tree is called the "[root](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/R/root.html) directory".

In your example, the project that contains all of the other projects is called the "root project".